# Determination of file extension not working for large files

Tags: php

I've coded the following script such that it shows error if any non-image file is uploaded or any image that is larger than 4 MB. Now, when I upload any image larger that 4 Mb or when I upload any small video file , it shows error and that's fine. But when I upload a larger file(say 50 MB or so), it doesn't show any error.. Rather it just shows blank page in registration.php. It should have redirected to 'complete_profile.php' if there was any error. This happens only with large file.. Why is this?

Code in registration.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['answerbox1']) && isset($_POST['answerbox5']) && isset($_POST['answerbox6']) && isset($_POST['sex']) && isset($_FILES['hiddenfilebutton'])){

        $img_name = $_FILES['hiddenfilebutton']['name'];
        $img_temp = $_FILES['hiddenfilebutton']['tmp_name'];
        $a = explode('.',$img_name);
        $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        $img_extension = strtolower(end($a));
        unset($a);
        $img_size = $_FILES['hiddenfilebutton']['size'];
        if(!getimagesize($img_temp)) {
            $error = 'Invalid image';
            $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
            header('Location: ../../../complete_profile.php');
        } else if($img_size > 4000000) {
            $error = 'Image should be less than 4 MB';
            $_SESSION['error'] = $error;    
            header('Location: ../../../complete_profile.php');
        } else if(!in_array($img_extension, $allowed_ext)) {
            $error = "Unsupported image format";
            $_SESSION['error'] = $error;    
            header('Location: ../../../complete_profile.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: ../../../desk.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: put this at the top of you're file                         error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: My guess would be to look at the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize config variables

Comment: It was post_max_size.. Thanks a tonne.. Changed it and everything's fine..